# tablelayout tablerow layout alignment

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I am totally out of idea why test,test1,test2,test3 is not proper align with first row. First row is refer to test,2012,test,test. I want the following row follow the first row in the table.

xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tl"
        android:weightSum="5"
        >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#27160e" >
    
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#fad06e"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Project" />
       
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#fad06e"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Project2" />
       
         <TableLayout
             android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
       android:stretchColumns="*"
       >
       
             
       
       <TableRow>
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#fad06e"
            android:text="Cost"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_span="2" />
   </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            >
        
        
      
         
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#fad06e"
            android:text="2011" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#fad06e"
            android:text="2012" />
                  </TableRow>
                  </TableLayout>
    </TableRow>

  <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="test" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
          
            android:layout_weight="1"
          
            android:text="test" />
      <TableLayout android:stretchColumns="*"
          android:layout_weight="3">
          <TableRow>
                <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            
            android:text="test" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
           
            android:text="test" />
              
          </TableRow>
          
      </TableLayout>
      
  </TableRow>

   
    
</TableLayout>
```

Code:

```
TableLayout tl;
        
        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tl);
        
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            
            // Create the table row
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setId(100+x);

            TextView lblrecID = new TextView(this);
            lblrecID.setId(200+x);
            lblrecID.setText("test");
            lblrecID.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); 
            LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
            lblrecID.setLayoutParams(params);
            tr.addView(lblrecID);// add the column to the table row here

            TextView lblrecName = new TextView(this);
            lblrecName.setId(200+x);// define id that must be unique
            lblrecName.setText("test1");
            lblrecName.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            lblrecName.setLayoutParams(params);
            tr.addView(lblrecName); // add the column to the table row here
            
            TableLayout tl1 = new TableLayout(this);
            LayoutParams params1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 3f);
            tl1.setStretchAllColumns(true);
            tl1.setLayoutParams(params1);
            TableRow tr2 = new TableRow(this);
            
            TextView lblrecID1 = new TextView(this);
            lblrecID1.setId(200+x);
            lblrecID1.setText("test2");
            lblrecID1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); 
            tr2.addView(lblrecID1);// add the column to the table row here

            TextView lblrecName1 = new TextView(this);
            lblrecName1.setId(200+x);// define id that must be unique
            lblrecName1.setText("test3");
            lblrecName1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tr2.addView(lblrecName1); // add the column to the table row here
            tl1.addView(tr2);     
            // finally add this to the table row
            
            tr.addView(tl1);
            //tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            
            
        }
```

Result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I don't get what you want. Is it like this layout maybe?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tl"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="*">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#27160e" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Project"
        android:textColor="#fad06e"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Project2"
        android:textColor="#fad06e"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Cost"
        android:textColor="#fad06e"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2011"
        android:textColor="#fad06e"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2012"
        android:textColor="#fad06e"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test" />
</TableRow>

 <TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Edited my answer. Please be more specific. What you want? The column `Cost` should be empty or what?

Comment: not proper align. Can the test align with test column, test1 align with 2012 column and so on...